# Not able to archive the last day log file in log4j2 by using TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

Currently using the below properties file. Able to archive the sizedbasedtriggeringpolicy. But if day changes from one to another the last log file for the previous date not getting archive.

```
property.basePath = H:/Application/Application_Name
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSXXX} %-5p [%tid] [%t] [%r] %x %c %M - %m%n
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = fileLogger
appender.rolling.fileName=${basePath}/hello_log-${date:MM-dd-yyyy}.log
appender.rolling.filePattern=${basePath}/$${date:yyyyMMdd}/helloSTC_log-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.zip
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSXXX} %-5p [%tid] [%t] [%r] %x %c %M - %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type=SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=100MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 100
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.type = Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.basePath = ${basePath}
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.maxDepth = 2
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.type = IfLastModified
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.age = 30d
logger.application.name = com.example
logger.application.level = info
logger.application.additivity = false
logger.application.appenderRef.rolling.ref = fileLogger
rootLogger.level = error
rootLogger.additivity = false
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = fileLogger
```

Comment: If I remove the date pattern from log file name then it is happening correctly. But I need to add the date pattern in my file name.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using only SimpleDateFormat pattern ?

```
appender.rolling.fileName=${basePath}/hello_log-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log
appender.rolling.filePattern=${basePath}/%d{yyyyMMdd}/helloSTC_log-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.zip
```